# Window onload event in jquery is not firing

Tags: jquery

Why window onload is not firing in the below code. Is there any way i can load HTML in the document ready event? Actually i would like to show preloader when the page starts to load and remove the loader once the document is fully loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
            alert("document is ready");
            $(window).load(function() {
                // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
                alert("window is loaded");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="load"></div>
    <div id="contents">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ive never seen $(document).ready and window.load nested like that. Im almost positive that they should not be nested like that. They are both the "top" functions if you will

Answer (score 0):

First hide contents div in css, then in javascript hide loader div, once it's done show the contents div.

Demonstration:

https://codepen.io/perodo/pen/bGGrOra

Code source :

```
<style>
#load {
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
z-index:3;
border: 4px solid #Fff;
top: 50%;
z-index:1;
}

#contents{
height: 100%;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
background:#dcdcdc;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative; 
display:none;
}
</style>
<div id="load">loading...</div>
<div id="contents">
<p>test</p>
</div> 
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#load").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function(){ 
        $("#contents").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: delay is something we're forcing the page to wait for 2 seconds right?... my problem is that some pages take 2 seconds, some take 6 seconds, some take 10 secs too.

Comment: oh okay then just remove the delay  "  .delay(2000) "

Comment: removing delay will fire fadeout immediately and start to load content

Comment: I'm wondering most of the preloader examples that i noticed like we're forcing page to wait for few seconds.

Comment: Until we get the response from server, dom will not load ryt

Comment: Yes most of them are "fake" loader, to get a "real" one use this lib : https://9elements.github.io/loadie.js/

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
        alert("document is ready");

    });
      $(window).on('load', function () {
        alert("Window Loaded");
      });
    </script>
```

hope this will work!!